# error in r code sentiment analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to write a code in r to do sentiment analysis by exporting and analyzing tweets,the following code is supposed to clean the tweet call up the sentiment package do  the scoring and return back the result , this code has been cited in many tech blogs the code is as follows :

```
score.sentiment = function(sentences , pos.words, neg.words , progress='none')
{
 require(plyr)
 require(stringr)
 scores = laply(sentences,function(sentence,pos.words,neg.words)
 {
     sentence =gsub('[[:punct:]]','',sentence)
     sentence =gsub('[[:cntrl]]','',sentence)
     sentence =gsub('\\d+','',sentence)
     sentence=tolower(sentence)
     word.list=str_split(sentence,'\\s+')
     words=unlist(word.list)
     pos.matches=match(words,pos.words)
     neg.matches=match(words,neg.words)
     score=sum(pos.matches)-sum(neg.matches)
     return(score)
 },pos.words,neg.words,.progress=.progress)
 scores.df=data.frame(scores=scores,text=sentences)
 return(scores.df)
}
```

However i keep on getting the following error:

Error in score.sentiment(Datasetgaza$text, pos.words, neg.words, .progress = "text") : 
  unused argument (.progress = "text")

The argument passed was:
 gaza.scores=score.sentiment(Datasetgaza$text,pos.words,neg.words,.progress='text')

any help with the code would be very appreciated

Comment: Option of the function is `progress`, but in the code, it is `.progress`. I guess the former is a typo. Try by replacing `progress` with `.progress`.

Comment: Give us a link to one of these "many tech blogs" because they must have been using the same buggy code that you pasted.

Comment: According to [this page](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/twitter-text-mining-r-slides/), there is a typo in the code reproduced above.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a '.' in front of progress.
sure this will help.

```
    score.sentiment = function(sentences , pos.words, neg.words , .progress='none')
{
 require(plyr)
 require(stringr)
 scores = laply(sentences,function(sentence,pos.words,neg.words)
 {
     sentence =gsub('[[:punct:]]','',sentence)
     sentence =gsub('[[:cntrl]]','',sentence)
     sentence =gsub('\\d+','',sentence)
     sentence=tolower(sentence)
     word.list=str_split(sentence,'\\s+')
     words=unlist(word.list)
     pos.matches=match(words,pos.words)
     neg.matches=match(words,neg.words)
     score=sum(pos.matches)-sum(neg.matches)
     return(score)
 },pos.words,neg.words,.progress=.progress)
 scores.df=data.frame(scores=scores,text=sentences)
 return(scores.df)
}
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything new, to already posted comments and answers.